# Cannot insert or update to new column database after updating flask model

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently make a flask app and using flask-alchemy. I'm already has a model like this

```
class SheetData(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
"""
Data relation from sheet and table
"""
serialize_only = ('id', 'start_row', 'start_col', 'use_header', 'use_index', 'table_ref')

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
sheet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sheet.id'), nullable=False)
start_row = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='1')
start_col = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='1')

table_ref = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Its work fine. I able to add and update new object and push to database until i add new column attribute to my model to be something like this

```
class SheetData(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
"""
Data relation from sheet and table
"""
serialize_only = ('id', 'start_row', 'start_col', 'use_header', 'use_index', 'table_ref')

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
sheet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sheet.id'), nullable=False)
start_row = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='1')
start_col = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='1')

use_header = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
use_index = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

table_ref = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Im already run

```
flask db stamp head
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

And the table in database already updated. But its not insert or update those 2 column only in database
This is my insert method

```
new_sheet_data = SheetData(
                sheet_id    = sheet_id,
                start_row   = new_start_row,
                start_col   = new_start_col,
                use_header  = new_use_header,
                use_index   = new_use_index,
                table_ref   = new_table_ref
            )
db.session.add(new_sheet_data)
db.session.commit()
```

and update method

```
sheet_data = SheetData.query.get(id)
 
if sheet_data is not None:
    sheet_data.sheet_id     = sheet_id
    sheet_data.start_row    = start_row
    sheet_data.start_col    = start_col
    sheet_data.use_header   = use_header
    sheet_data.use_index    = use_index
    sheet_data.table_ref    = table_ref
    
    db.session.commit()
```

Can anyone figure out this? Thanks

Comment: how you run"flask db migrate"?
in my way, i run "db.create_all()".
and i can't update the table.
so i delete the the old table and "db.create_all()" again.
I didn't have the problem you had...
i use the mysql, mybe you are not ?

Comment: Im Following to this site for flask migration https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and use microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i delete the column and re run flask migration and all worked